# Does Capybara require JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, capybara

I'm building a Rails 3 app. I'm trying to learn Cucumber with Capybara.

- Do I need JRuby to run Capybara via Cucumber?

I've used Webrat, but many people seem to be using Capybara,
so I'd love to try.

I don't need JavaScript testing right away, but I want to install
Capybara if I need in the end.

I read and read the Capybara documentation, but couldn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Capybara myself, but from what I can glean from [the readme](http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.rdoc), it doesn't *look* like it requires JRuby, **depending on the JavaScript driver you use**. For instance, if you want to use Culerity, then **yes you need JRuby**, since it needs to be in your path.

Are you having difficulty installing Capybara?

Comment: So, what driver does Capybara use by default? Selenium? Selenium seems to be more hassle than JRuby!

Comment: @TK: using Selenium as the driver (2.0, aka WebDriver, **not** RC) seems pretty simple to set up. Looks like you only need to have Firefox installed.

Comment: The default driver is rack-test.

Answer (score 2):

Capybara does not require jRuby or the Selenium-RC drivers.

Simply do the following to setup Cucumber with Capybara.

```
$ gem install capybara cucumber
$ rails generate cucumber --capybara
```